# Why are old outdated blocks loaded after restarting the ethereum node?

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node

I have an Ethereum full node running on a vps, and I noticed that it was abruptly out of sync for three days. I searched in the logs, and found this. My system daemon received a shutdown signal, and rebooted the node:
[image]

I scrolled through the logs further, and drew attention to the lines when loading the node, which indicate the loaded blocks and headers:
[image]

As you can see, my node has actual blocks, but after rebooting for some reason, it started with irrelevant blocks three days ago. I suppose the fact is that they are marked as "most recent local full block", in this case how to make the actual blocks become most recent local full block.

You can also see in the second screenshot that in the first data set, the "most recent local full block" is only 39 seconds old, but after that there is a "Head state missing, repairing number=16,514,819 hash=790707..1934b0 snaproot=a21c30..dd9906" and the second data set is loaded, where the "most recent local full block" is 3 days old. I also don't understand what this is related to, if you understand, can you please explain!

Answer (score 2):

After the run, the node makes handshake with other nodes and receive the latest block from them. So after reboot, the most recent local full block can be the latest block.(as you know, 39s ago means it is the one of the most recent block). Otherwise, the node can not know the current status of the Ethereum chain.

But after receive the latest block, the node analyzes that they did not sync for three days. (The node understand this because it is already gotten the latest block)
And the node need to show users that the node did not sync.
And it is

> "Head state missing, repairing number=16,514,819 hash=790707..1934b0
> snaproot=a21c30..dd9906"

This is because the latest head state is not current. (It is a little complicate to describe the detail of this)
And after this, the node understands that the latest stable block is 3 days ago one.